# How to calculate the probability of survival in the following Russian Roulette?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are 6 chambers in a gun and 2 chambers have bullets.

What is the probability of surviving first shot and second shot?

In my opinion, surviving the first shot is easily $\frac46$, but surviving the second shot needs analysis:

The chance of surviving when the two bullets are next to each other is $\frac34$ because there are 5 chambers in total left. The connected bullets can stay in 4 positions in total and there 3 positions in which the second shot is empty chamber.

The chance of surviving when the two bullets are not next to each other is $\frac12$. Here is the image in my brain, suppose the first shot chamber is slot $1$ (which is empty), if one bullet is at slot $2$, then there $3$ possible positions. If one bullet is at slot $3$, then there are $2$ possible positions. If one bullet is at slot $4$, then there are $1$ possible positions. So the surviving rate is $\frac{1+2}{6}=\frac36=\frac12$.

My solution is very inconvenient. Is there a more efficient way to solve this question?

Comment: There are $\binom 62$ ways to place the bullets.  There are $\binom 42$ ways to place them so that the first two chambers are empty.  Thus your answer is the ratio $\frac {4\times 3}{6\times 5}=\frac 25$.

Comment: Does the "probability of surviving the second shot" mean the probability that the second pull of the trigger falls on an empty chamber, given that the first pull of the trigger falls on an empty chamber?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: the question you wrote is "what is the probability of surviving first and second shot".  that's $\frac 25$.  If you have survived the first, that means that there are $3$ empty chambers out of $5$, so the conditional probability is $\frac 35$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that the first pull of the trigger drops the hammer on
an empty chamber (so the player survives).
Let $B$ be the event that the trigger is pulled a second time and drops the
hammer on an empty chamber.

A complete answer depends on how the revolver is loaded.
Assuming the revolver has six chambers<sup>*</sup>,
there are $\binom 62 = 15$ different ways to put two cartridges into
the chambers if we distinguish each chamber from the other
and do not distinguish the cartridges.
We can give each of these sequences an equal chance of occurrence
by choosing any of the six chambers at random,
loading a cartridge in it, then choosing one of the remaining five empty
chambers at random and loading it.
Whether or not we spin the cylinder after loading it, each possible
sequence of empty and loaded chambers,
starting with the chamber on which the hammer will first fall,
has a $\frac1{15}$ chance of occurring.

If the procedure is as random as that, then $P(A \cap B) = \frac25$.
This can be shown as follows:

Number the chambers $1$ through $6$ at the time the revolver is ready for the first pull of the trigger, with number $1$ being the chamber on which the hammer will fall on that first trigger pull.
Use the model of the distribution of cartridges in which we load one at
a time into a random chamber as described above.
There is a $\frac23$ chance the first
cartridge loaded went into one of the chambers $3, 4, 5,$ or $6$;
and given that it did, there is a $\frac35$ chance that the second cartridge
also went into one of those chambers.
The chance that *neither* cartridge is in chambers $1$ or $2$
(the necessary and sufficient condition to be able to pull the trigger
twice without firing) is therefore $\frac23 \times \frac35 = \frac25$.

Of course $P(A) = \frac23$, and the probability that the second pull of the trigger drops the hammer on an empty chamber when the first pull also did is $P(B \mid A)$, given by the formula
$$P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{2/5}{2/3} = \frac35.$$

But it would be relatively difficult to produce such a random distribution
of cartridges in chambers using an actual revolver without either player
knowing anything about the relative locations of the cartridges.
The most likely ways would involve some other person who used another
random process (such as rolling dice) to decide which two chambers to load.

Supposing the players themselves load the revolver, at least one of them
knows the *relative* positions of the cartridges, and the other either
knows or may try to guess; in neither case are the locations as random
as a third party can produce. So you have up to three cases:
cartridges loaded in adjacent chambers,
cartridges loaded in chambers separated by one empty chamber,
cartridges loaded in opposite chambers (separated by two empty chambers).

For cartridges loaded in adjacent chambers, given that neither of those
chambers is chamber $1$, there are (as you deduced) four possible ways the
two cartridges may be arranged in all but one of which the player
survives the second pull of the trigger.
So in this case, $P(B \mid A) = \frac34$.
Moreover,
$P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A)\,P(A) = \frac34 \times \frac23 = \frac12$.

For either of the other two cases, there are four empty chambers.
Two of these are followed by an empty chamber, the other two by a loaded chamber. If the first pull of the trigger falls on an empty chamber,
one of these four chambers was chamber $1$, but each is equally likely.
There are therefore two chances out of four that the next chamber
is unloaded so, $P(B \mid A) = \frac12$.
Then $P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A)\,P(A) = \frac12 \times \frac23 = \frac13$.

---

<sup>*</sup>Here is a somewhat irrelevant historical footnote. In [the story that popularized (and possibly invented) the term "Russian roulette" in 1937](https://christopherothen.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/the-man-who-invented-russian-roulette/), the "game" is said to have originated in the Russian army in 1917. The Russian service revolver in 1917 had seven chambers. (It also could not be operated in the way described in the story.)